# How do I single out a child element from a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to mimic snow for a website, right now I have 5 snow particles and I am trying to get them to randomize their left position after they pass through the bottom viewport line. Currently I can get the first child to randomize after 6 seconds (Its animation duration is 7 seconds but it lines up for some reason). However I can't figure out how to specify which child or even figure out how the first child is being affected and not the parent. Some help would be appreciated.

```js
let snow = document.querySelector('.snow');

function setProperty(position) {
  snow.style.left = position + "%";
}

function changeAnimationPos() {
    let position = Math.random() * 101;
    setProperty(position);
}

setInterval(changeAnimationPos, 6000)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(snow, skyblue);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#header {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.8px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: snow;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    z-index: 999;
}

/*-----Snow-----*/

.snowfall {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.snow {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: fall 4s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.snow:nth-child(1) {
    animation-duration: 6s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 20%;
}

.snow:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 30%;
}

.snow:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 40%;
}

.snow:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
}

@keyframes fall{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(110vh);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>Matching Game Project</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <header id="header">Matching Game</header>
        <div class="snowfall">
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="snow.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nth-child selector? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

The function `querySelector()` returns only the first matching element as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?retiredLocale=de#return_value). If you want to address all elements, you can use `getElementsByClassName()`. You will get an array with all matching elements which you can then iterate over.
As commented below, you could probably also use `querySelectorAll()`. A difference to `getElementsByClassName()` is, that `querySelectorAll()` returns a non-live NodeList, whereas `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live HTMLCollection.

```js
let snow = document.getElementsByClassName('snow');

function setPosition(element) {
    element.style.left = Math.random() * 100 + "%";
}

let i = 0;
for (const flake of snow) {
    setTimeout(() => setInterval(() => setPosition(flake), 6000), 1000 * i);
    i++;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(snow, skyblue);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#header {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.8px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: snow;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    z-index: 999;
}

/*-----Snow-----*/

.snowfall {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.snow {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: fall 4s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.snow:nth-child(1) {
    animation-duration: 6s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 20%;
}

.snow:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 30%;
}

.snow:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 40%;
}

.snow:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
}

@keyframes fall{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(110vh);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>Matching Game Project</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <header id="header">Matching Game</header>
        <div class="snowfall">
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
            <div class="snow"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="snow.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to address one specific element, I would recommend to use different ids (or unique classnames).

Comment: Or use `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @HereticMonkey , I edited my answer accordingly.